# Best way to implement transaction-per-request in Linq-to-Sql MVC App

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, transactions, request

In my case, I create one-per-request `DataContext` and `TransactionScope`. So I could catch an exception and rollback a transaction, or not, if there is no exceptions.

Currently, I have declared a dependency of `TransactionScope` in my main root abstract controller class, and the transaction is auto created on each request and then, in that controller's `OnActionExecuted` method I either do commit or not the transaction.

As it turns out, I need at least a **earlier** transaction creation, what seems to be so when `AuthorizeAttribute`s are being invoked in some requests, and they also use the DB connection.

Also, I suspect there must be cleaner way to create a one-per-request transaction, than the way I do it.

---

1 So what is the best way, while not using some other ORMs like nhibernate, to create a transaction for controller's actions in the moment of a request is being created and dispose them at the end of that request?

---

2 Is there any way to split my controller's actions in some way of channels, by specifying IDs, so that actions with the same ID would not get executed by webserver simulteneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it did turn our out, there is no better way of doing it, especially since noone answered it and noone even viewed such an interestiong topic.